# "Was orange one of your highly rated option?"

Tags: word-choice, questions

On my website, users were asked to rate a list of fruits (between 1 to 10 for each fruit) and after that I carried out a little survey (memory check).

In the survey, I want to ask the users something like

> "Was orange one of your highly rated options?"

This sentence sounds good? Do you have any suggestion?

Note that orange may be rated with 10 points and apple too, so the words "one of" are necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question will sound less awkward if you insert an article (a or an) before the fruit names. "Was **an** orange one of your highly rated options?"

In your survey, the fruits are nouns (orange, apple, etc.) and not an adjective describing something's color.